# Arrows diseappear on Safari Mac OS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm working on a [wordpress website](http://quentincarnaille.com/) that uses the fullpage.js plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullpage/).

There is a problem with the fullpage's arrows (left and right) on Safari on Mac OS: they seem to appear and disappear randomly. These arrows are printed through the CSS's `::before` and `::after` directives. From what I saw during my Googling, `::before` and `::after` compatibility with Safari is known to be problematic.

Has anyone already had and maybe solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using and old version of fullPage.js. (2.4.3). That's like 22 versions old!

Try to update to the latest one (2.6.5).

Or, if you can not updated because of limitations with the wordpresss plugin, then, just add the following to your CSS stylesheet:

```
.fp-controlArrow {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! Indeed I cannot choose the fullpage.js version because it is a wordpress plugin.

Comment: @Chrls wordpress plugin should work independently of the fullpage.js version. Being 23 versions out of date is not good...